# Add Extra label in a pie chart

Tags: chart.js

Is there a away to add an extra label at the bottom if a pie graph like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it as follows:

```
 options: {
  legend: {
  display: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Custom Chart Title',
        position: 'bottom'
    }
}
```

You can also find some more details on the official documentation, here:
[Chart JS Legend Official Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html)

Comment: This just move the legend at the bottom, I need to keep everything as is, and add new text https://jsfiddle.net/k1uc5phn/1/

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment. Try the new configuration, I tested it, seems to work!